# Cross-platform source control?

Tags: java, .net, visual-studio-2008, eclipse, version-control

We're doing development for both .NET (Using VS 2008) and Java (using eclipse)

Currently, we're using CVS, but there isn't really a good plugin for Visual Studio 2008, so I'm looking at changing to something that has better support for VS 2008 and Eclipse.

My initial thought was SVN, as it is really close to CVS, but I'm a bit tempted to use something like Mercurial.  I'm looking for something that is simple to  use, and has good plug-in support for both platforms.

Comment: Subversion might not be the worst choice for you, especially because it is relatively easy to migrate you CVS Repository to Subversion. Haven't tried any Plugins for VS though (usually used Tortoise SVN for that).

Comment: Are you sure changing version control systems isn't just treating a symptom, not a cause?

Why are you trying to improve the rate of checkins? Are some developers only committing once a week, leading to long merge sessions/broken builds?

Comment: It will be treating a symptom.  The problem is that some developers are just not checking in at all unless asked, and merging is a royal pain if they are merging a month's worth of changes.

Comment: Did you move to SVN or Mercurial then? Curious as I'm looking for a source control for both platforms too. Although, I don't have an existing source control like you do so I'm more open.

Comment: @learner We moved to SVN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can tell you that there are really nice plugins for Subversion for Eclipse and Visual Studio 2008 ([AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) for Visual Studio).
You have to make sure to download the daily builds of AnkhSVN if you plan to use it with the most recent subversion version.
Additionally there are tools (http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/) to migrate your data from CSV to SVN.

For Mercurial oder Git - I don't have got any experience with those.

I think SVN will give you the smoothest transision - but it won't give you the "big revolution" (if this is what you are after)

Comment: I would agree.  SVN is definitely the best choice if you don't want to rock the boat too much.  I really like GIT, but it does require a different mind set.

Answer (score 2):

We're a .NET, Java, and Rails shop

We used Subversion for years and its a fantastic system, did everything we thought we needed from an SCM. About 9 months ago we started playing around with Github.com whilst developing a Rails application (unavoidable in the Rails community).

Since then we've shifted over to Github.com completely using private repos for our closed-source commercial software developments.

Git has made us not break a build or clobber code in months - something that used to happen from time to time and made us loose a day's work trying to rectify the problem. Subversion doesn't provide you with the flexibility in your working methods that Git does. If you're in trouble (a broken build or a hot fix), Subversion won't help you it'll even work against you. Its branch/merge mechanism is very difficult to use because it doesn't keep track of the origin of the branch. Also when you merge back, your change history is modified such that all changes by the team in a particular branch are attributed to the user performing the merge. Git is also lightning fast as the whole repo that you work on is local, something that is very noticable when you're working from remote locations.

That said, Subversion will take you a week or two to get proficient in, Git takes at least a month, especially if you're coming from Subversion or CVS. If you pretend its just a more modern SVN or CVS, you'll get frustrated by the lack of improvement in your coding workflow and you'll become annoyed by the multitude of commands.

We have a 3-branch setup: hotfix<->master<->development. In normal conditions the dev team will work in the development branch. For each user story the developer will create a branch off development: development<->user story. When the story is finished the user story is merged with development and the user story branch may be deleted. This goes on and on, and master stays stable and unaffected until the build manager decides its safe to merge all the changes in development back into master. If in the mean time a customer phones and requires a hotfix, that too is done in isolation from master and can be merged into the rest of the codebase (master&development) at a suitable point in the future.

Now wrt to GUIs and SCM. We avoid them like the plague. GUIs are bad for working with SCMs. I know - controversial, but hear me out. The command line will slow you down more than a GUI does and when you're working with an SCM and there's a high-chance that you're going to do something bad or destructive to your central repo, slow is a good thing. Slow makes you think about your actions. All the typical GUIs that I've seen (EclipseSVN, TortoiseGit/SVN) all preselect your recent changes as being part of the commit you're about to make, whether those changes are ready to be committed or not. BAD!!!! You need to think about your commits and how lumpy or granular they need to be - command lines do a better job than GUIs in this regard.
All our .NET coders, who are naturally drawn to performing tasks via GUIs, use command line Git and used command line SVN before that, just for those reasons outlined above. It gave them a greater sense of control.

Comment: Does Github store the entire repository locally?  Is that more for speed or for redundancy?

How do you convince your developers to switch to using the command line over a GUI, and more importantly, how do you ensure that they check in their code in a timely manner?

Comment: Great comment - but I have to say that I think that is really nice to have version control integrated into your IDE (if you are using an IDE - and if you are using a GUI IDE, meaning using a GUI version control tool).
I can understand your reservation - but for the daily development cycle it is very nice to have your update - change code - commit cycle in a single tool. It makes using vc easier for the normal user. For all the other things I understand your concerns.

Comment: @Jesse Git (not Github per se') is completely distributed. Every location where a repository is held (such as Github) is a complete copy of the whole repository, which sounds like a lot but in reality isn't. We've got about 30man years of development taking up about 400Mb of hard disk space. Having the whole repo locally means working with a repo is very very quick. Subversion is comparatively slow in this regard, because any operations like diffs, status checks, or log file checking, Subversion needs to perform across the network.

Comment: Having a local repo is primarily a speed- and working-offline-thing, rather than redundancy. Redundancy is a side effect

Now the notion of 'central'... Subversion has a concept of central repository, i.e the SVN server, much like CVS does too. Git is different, the 'central' repository is only classed as central because everyone in the team has deemed it to be. There's nothing in Git that makes it any more special or powerful than the repo thats currently on a developer's laptop. So purely by common agreement are the Git repositories we maintain in our Github account deemed 'central'.

Comment: Two of our developers could go live on the North Pole, and via a LAN share code from their local repos using Git, without ever touching the 'central' repo on Github. Then after they've defrosted, connect back to Github and push their changes back into the 'central' repo. Very powerful, requires good discipline though.

Having developers check in code in a timely manner is a process rather than technology problem. Git is no better or worse than SVN or CVS in this regard, other than the speed of operating locally causes less of an interruption to the development process.

Answer (score 1):

- [VisualSVN](http://visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) client for Visual
  Studio
- [SubClipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) for Eclipse
- [VisualSVN Server](http://visualsvn.com/server/) for the server

Answer (score 1):

Having used svn with both Eclipse and Visual Studio, I find that the eclipse plugins (especially [subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/)) are generally more seamlessly integrated into the IDE.  Ankh and VisualSVN both do a very good job, but I tend to prefer ToirtoiseSVN when working with .net.  In Eclipse I almost never resort to ToirtoiseSVN.

To be honest though, I think the IDE plugin shouldn't drive your decision too much.

Comment: As stated in another answer, it is really to get people to check in more often.  Otherwise, we'd just stay with CVS.

Answer (score 0):

We use both VSS (and now subversion) for both J2EE and .NET on different projects. Both seem to work OK.

Why are you so hung up on IDE pulgins? Personally, I could take'em or leav'em... I put them in the "kitch which doesn't add any real value" bucket.

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: I think they are quite nice, because they work were you spend most of the time (if you are using an IDE) - e.g. I really think the pending changes window in Visual Studio is great

Comment: We have a few developers who tend to forget to check things in if they're using source control outside of the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ongoing debate between [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) and [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/), if you decide to go with SVN.

Personally, I like Ankh. It is free, more intuitive for me, and provides more useful feedback on my project's state. I have had some corruption issues, though, but nothing that cost me more than a few minutes.

Comment: Is AnkhSVN really ready for primetime? Last time I tried it out, it made Visual Studio crash every few minutes.

Comment: Its certainly doing better. Never had a crash - been using it since around February.

Comment: We (two developpers) are using it full time and it is working well. Some things are better solved with Tortoise SVN, but for the daily "update, change code, commit" cycle it is doing well

Answer (score 0):

I use [Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/) from [SourceGear](http://www.sourcegear.com/).  It's simple to use and has great IDE integration with Visual Studio and Eclipse.  It's also fully tested on Linux using Mono.

It's free to use for single users, so you can try before you buy.

Check it out and see what you think.  http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/

Answer (score 0):

Try [Plastic SCM](http://www.plasticscm.com) working on Linux, Mac and Windows. GUI based replication, branch explorer, efficient branching and merging (merge tracking included, move and renames too), ACL based security...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/).  Not free, but cross-platform and very good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on this, but I have been woefully underwhelmed at GUI, or IDE SCM extensions. I've been using SVN, and GIT fairly nicely with projects hosted on sourceforge. My 2 cents worth.  CHEERS!